# What happened to the WordPress dashboard?

Tags: dashboard

I installed MAMP on my system, installed WordPress, installed a theme and customized it and everything worked great. However, when I started MAMP today it does not take me to the WordPress dashboard, but rather directly to the website itself.

If someone can help me resolve this so I can gain access back to my dashboard, it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to http://yoursite.dev/wp-admin

If you are still getting redirected to the main site check your database, MAMP I beleive comes with PHPmyAdmin, login to that and check your SITE_URL in the WP_OPTIONS table and then check the WP_USERS table to see if your user account is still registered as an admin.

Comment: Thanks. So, I did go to phpMyAdmin ran a simple SQL query on WP_USERS and NO user came up whatsoever. The simple query was SELECT * FROM wp_users. The siteurl value looks to be okay though. Not sure why there are no users listed in WP_USERS.

Comment: Sorry, my user account was right in front of me and it was registered still as an admin, I must be blind. Anyway, for some odd reason the password was completely wrong. So, I changed it back and then changed the hash to MD5, saved and refreshed and logged back using http://mysite/wp-admin. I believe this happened, because I used a WP Reset plugin and reset my database, that would explain it. Thanks for your help